# Is there an easy way to remove items from a page depending on what I write in a textbox (similar to autocomplete)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to implement a feature where if there are 50 links on a page for example, you start typing in a box and the items start to disappear depending on what you type. It is the same idea of autocomplete but instead of creating a list of possible links, you remove the irrelevant ones from the page.

I am sorry if my explanation is not clear enough, if you need more details please ask me and I will answer in the comments.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, you could iterate over all `a` elements every x milliseconds as the user types, and hide the ones that don't match the input (perhaps using a regex).

Comment: @Cameron that would be very inefficient

Comment: @Livingston: Not necessarily if the intervals were large enough (obviously it would be undesirable for the code to keep running after the user stopped typing though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var anchors = $('a');

$('#filter').bind('keyup', function () {
  var filterValue = $.trim(this.value);

  anchors.hide().filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(filterValue) !== -1;
  }).show();
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PF2Ac/)

Comment: Why unnecessarily hide all items and then loop through all of them again?

Comment: Yeah I agree and it's slow. I just tried a different approach.

Comment: Is there a way to make that when they disappear you remove their space from the page. For example, if you try this when you have <br/> or if they are each on a different lines, the lines become empty and the spaces of these lines remain there which looks weird. Is there a way to remove the existence of that space?(let me know if I didn't explain this well)

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/PF2Ac/2/ and search for sample, the middle line disappears but there is white space there, is it possible to push the third line to be the second one (remove the space) instead of leaving white space? Thanks!

Comment: @user if you want the links to appear on it's own line, I'd recommend using `ul`, then the content will flow accordingly  [jsfiddle.net/PF2Ac/4](http://jsfiddle.net/PF2Ac/4/). Trying to handle `br` wouldn't be foolproof unless it's absolutely essential.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".selector-for input").keyup(function(){
  var text = this.value;
  $(".selector-for a").each(function() {
    var it = $(this);
    it.text().indexOf(text) < 0 ? it.hide() : it.show()
  });
});
```

Comment: It's better to cache the `$(".selector-for a")`, rather than matching the elements everytime you press the key.

Comment: It depends on the situation. jQuery docs explicitly mention that you should not hold the result for too long.

Comment: Here you are looking up for `.selector-for a` everytime the user presses a key in the textfield, so you're querying the DOM 3 to 4 times every second (depending on the typing speed)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this.Call this function in your 'onKeyUp' event of the textbox

```
 function hideFiltered(){
    var text=$("#textbox").val();
    var links=$('a[name="linksToHide"]');

    for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    link=links[i];
    if(link.html().indexof(text)>0){
    link.hide();
    }else{
    link.show();

    }

    }


    }



    }
```

Comment: `name` is supposed to be unique on a page, why did't you use `class`?

Comment: `name` does not need to be unique, `id` should. But I agree that class should be used. Also the code is not really correct. `indexOf` comparison should take into account 0 position (thus `>=`).